# mysql, store schema in other partition/file system?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

All my databases are fairly small so it is no problem to use MariaDB on my laptop. But now I will have to work with a database that is too large for my harddisk.

I guess that when I edit my.cnf, it should be possible to use an alternative datadir. This would have the disadvantage that I have to change or edit my.cnf every time I want to select another schema.
What I would like to see is that I can use/select the schema on the external disk, only when that disk is mounted.

Is this possible? If not, what are the alternatives?

Ben

Comment: You can consider running mysql instance in docker container and mount whatever datadir you want to it when you start container.

Answer (score 0):

Huh?  See the `DATA DIRECTORY` clause in `CREATE TABLE`.  To give you more specifics, we need to know

- What OS you are using.
- What `ENGINE` the table is.
- What version of MySQL or MariaDB you are using.
- The value of `innodb_file_per_table`.